# Using Mailcatcher on XAMPP (do not receive mail)

Tags: php, xampp, mailcatcher

I do have a problem with `mailcatcher`.

My php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 1025
```

mail.php:

```
if( mail('test@example.com', 'My Subject', 'test' 'testexample.com') ) {
    echo "Mail Sent!"; 
} else {
    echo "not working";
}
```

I just read a lot of articles, StackOverflow questions about this problem, but I did not find anything that would work for me.

In my other project I use `composer` and `swiftmailer`. With `swiftmailer` `mailcatcher` catches my email, but in a project without `swiftmailer` `mailcatcher` doesn't work. Maybe someone does have the same problem ?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't restart my Apache Server when I change php.ini file information. Problem Solve.